# Find $\operatorname{min}(\omega\sqrt{2},\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $\omega$ be a primitive third root of unity with $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt{2})$.

Find $\operatorname{min}(\omega\sqrt{2},\mathbb{Q})$

Could anyone tell me how to find this? and generally which is the way to find similar problems with minimals?

Comment: I take it your notation means the minimal polynomial for that number over the rationals. Well, try raising the number to the sixth power. That should get you started.